# Reuse alias that shares an existing column name

Tags: mysql, alias

In MySQL I know I can reuse an alias in a query like this:

```
SELECT
  value_a + value_b as value_sum,
  (SELECT value_sum) + 5 as padded_sum
```

Is there any way to make this work if `padded_sum` is also the name of an existing column in one of the joined tables?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48c2c9/6

Answer (score 1):

For that you need user defined variables

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  @sum1 := value_a + value_b as value_sum,
  CONCAT('VALUE SUM: ', @sum1 + 5) as label,
  @sum2 := value_a + value_b as value_sum2,
  CONCAT('VALUE SUM: ', @sum2) as label2
 FROM item i
   LEFT JOIN item_sums isu USING (item_id);
```

Result

```
item_id     value_sum   label           value_sum2  label2
1           4           VALUE SUM: 9    4           VALUE SUM: 4
2           5           VALUE SUM: 10   5           VALUE SUM: 5
3           11          VALUE SUM: 16   11          VALUE SUM: 11
```

[sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48c2c9/8/0)

```
  SELECT 
      item_id,
      value_sum,
      CONCAT('VALUE SUM: ', value_sum + 5) as label,
      value_sum2,
      CONCAT('VALUE SUM: ', value_sum2) as label2
  FROM
  (SELECT
      item_id,
      value_a + value_b as value_sum,
      value_a + value_b as value_sum2
   FROM item i
       LEFT JOIN item_sums isu USING (item_id)) t1;
```

[sample2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48c2c9/10)

Comment: thanks, I am aware of this approach but can it be done without using variables?

Comment: yes, but it only gets uglier see changed answer, if you don't want to use the sum again

Comment: oh no ..lol that's not what I meant at all.  but thanks anyway.

Comment: what do you mean? there are no other possibilities, to use value_sum and this is more than enough

Comment: no that is not what you ask. but  for an answer you can identify every table and column by simple write table1.value_a  or table2.value_a, with a dot between you can combine databse table and column

Comment: If you look at my fiddle you'll notice that `CONCAT('VALUE SUM: ', (SELECT value_sum)) as label` fails because instead of taking `value_sum` as it's referenced in the query, it uses `isu.value_sum` which is not what I want there.  I want to use what's declared in the query, i.e., `value_a + value_b as value_sum`

Comment: and as i tried to explain 'test' as value value is niot a variable it is simole a text that mysql will interpret as columnname, see my second query) if you want to use content of a  variablem, you only can use user defined variable and to be again clear there is niothing between

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you're saying.  I want to backreference an alias that's incidentally also a column name.  I don't want the value from the table.  And I don't want to use variables or a subquery as demonstrated in your answer.  It's a good answer, just not what I'm looking for.  If what I'm asking is not possible, I will accept that but so far I'm still unsure.